# TortoiseGit How I can recognize project is not commited to remote repo?

Tags: git, gitlab, tortoisegit

I have moved recently from **TortoiseSVN** to **TortoiseGit** 
Im stil relatively new in GIT but if I understand well how Git works I can commit project to local repository (eg on my disk), then I should commit (sync) changes to remote repo from time to time.

I like this approach (I can finally work offline with repos) but Ive found Im quite often forgetting sync changes, so my code is at risk (eg if something will happen with my HDD).

How you deal with that?
Is there any option in TortoiseGit to set different overlay icons to see  which project is not sync / committed to remote repos yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ModifyExplorerTitle in the advanced settings which shows how far you are ahead/behind in the Windows Explorer title.

Here are further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76481896/13624968

Maybe this helps you or other developers having the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Just `push` (what you called here "sync") often enough to send your last commits to the remote end.

Comment: Case is I have dozen of projects, also traveling frequently so  I might miss something ... 
In SVN I could see what is not committed. Here I can see green icon but this might be local commit only. 
Initially I thought i might keep all project in same root folder and just right click on root. But in this case 'sync' option is not displayed and I have to do that project by project....

Comment: @Maciej we have the same issue for some non-programmer colleagues who recently switched from TortoiseSVN to TortoiseGit. Have you found any hassle-free method to solve your problem and to avoid having to click manually on push/sync? I tried to somehow change the green tick to only show up on successful push, but it seems that that is not possible...

Comment: I have found a small workaround while searching for solutions to this problem, I will post another answer.