# Is there a way to mark files as committed but not pushed on Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

My team isn't the best at checking on their own to see if they've pushed local commits. We work in documentation using XML files, and we all work on the master branch. We use the TortoiseGit client for Windows 10. Currently, there's an icon overlay for modified/unversioned files that changes to a green checkmark when committed/added.

However, it currently doesn't show an icon for commits that haven't been pushed to the remote. Is there anything I can do to add an overlay in Explorer for files that have been committed but not pushed? As it is right now, we keep getting conflicts because people are pulling without ever having pushed.

Comment: You should *not* all work on the master branch. You should work on your own branches, then do pull requests into the master branch.

Comment: Ideally yes, this would be awesome. The problem is a lot of the team isn't very tech-savvy and aren't open to the "added complexity" of branches and pull requests.

Comment: Then inform them that if they use the tool the "correct" way, this added complexity will solve their problems (and more) because their current workflow is flawed, as they've already noticed.

Comment: I'll definitely try! Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature and based on Windows limitations there won't be (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1074).

Answer (score 0):

There is a ModifyExplorerTitle which shows how far you are ahead/behind in the Windows Explorer title. You can see a screenshot in this SO question: [Get rid of extended git repository information shown in the title bar of explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75950114/13624968)

Here is the place where you can enable the feature: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3797