# Get rid of extended git repository information shown in the title bar of explorer

Tags: tortoisegit

It seems like tortoisegit added some information in the title bar of windows explorer.

It shows how far behind/ahead of the tracked repository we are.

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open [TortoiseGit settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html), go to [Advanced](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-registry), and disable `ModifyExplorerTitle`.